# dependent dropdown with jquery CODEIGNITER

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

i was finding a way to make a dependent dropdown in code igniter, suddenly, i saw this question, then i editted the codes to fit my needs, however, its not working for me, i am not familiar with jquery, but i need to finish this project as soon as possible. i dont know what my errors are. it just not output the data i want for the second dropdown

first dropdown

```
            <select class="form-control" name = "PROV_ID" id = "PROV_ID">
              <option></option>
                <?php foreach ($content as $cs) {?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $cs->PROV_ID; ?>"><?php echo $cs->PROVINCE; ?></option>
                <?php } ?> 
            </select>
```

second dropdown

```
            <select name = 'CT_ID' id = 'CT_ID'>
                <option value="">-- Select Type --</option>
            </select>
```

jquery

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $("#PROV_ID").change(function() {
        var PROV_ID= {"PROV_ID_id" : $('#PROV_ID').val()};
        console.log(PROV_ID);

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: PROV_ID,
          url: "<?php base_url(); ?>Employees/dependent_dropdown",

          success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, data){
            $('#CT_ID').append("<option value='"+data.CT_ID+"'>"+data.CITY+"</option>");
            });
           }
         });
       });
     });
</script>
```

controller

```
   public function dependent_dropdown()
   {
       if(isset($_POST['PROV_ID']))
       {

            $data = $_POST['PROV_ID'];
            $this->output
            ->set_content_type("application/json")
            ->set_output(json_encode($this->Employees_Model->getType($data)));
       }
   }
```

and finally the model

```
public function getType($data){

    $sql =  "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE PROV_ID = '".$data."'";
    $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

please help me find whats wrong with my codes.

Comment: the data that i will get is json right? so how can i fetch it?

Comment: model function doesn't `return` anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with returning something in the model.

```
public function getType($data)
    {

    $sql =  "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE PROV_ID = '".$data."'";
    $results = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $results
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your model as follwoing

```
public function getType($data){
 $sql =  "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE PROV_ID = '".$data."'";
 $query = $this->db->query($sql);
 return $query->result_array();
}
```